# error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1"

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Getting the below error message on Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin.iOS `12.4.0.64`.

Someone please assist us on this as it has blocked our complete deployment process now.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1" reference from "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"

This error message **comes ONLY after paring with mac which has same Xamarin.iOS, latest xCode and mono 5.18.** We do not have xamarin forms package added into our project as few of other issues reported due to xamarin forms version.

Comment: Hi , do you mean it occurs after pairing with mac , or when running with Xamarin.iOS 12.4.0.64 .  What changes in project after previous successful running ?

Comment: happens after pairing and start debugging..

Comment: OK , if possible , you can have a try with Visual Studio 2019 . If related to some function of iOS 13 , VS 2019 will support all of them .